# SQL Search for row when 2 column in same row equal 2 values

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

let's supose I have this table in my db:

```
----------------------------------
| userID    | meta     | value   |
|--------------------------------|
|   1       | age      |  20     |
|   1       | gender   |  M      |
|   1       | country  | Brazil  |
|   2       | age      |  21     |
|   3       | age      |  22     |
|   3       | gender   |  F      |
|   3       | country  |  Brazil |
----------------------------------
```

And I want to get all userID that are from Brazil and the age is more than 18 years... 
I tried something similar to this:

```
SELECT distinct(userID)
FROM table
WHERE (meta = age AND value > 18) AND (meta = country AND value = 'Brazil')
```

But this didn't work, which is the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your query, means that you want to have (meta > 18) and (country = Brazil) all on the same line.  But that never happens, since your table is not built like that.

You can do this to query on one meta/value pair:

```
SELECT userID
FORM User
WHERE (meta = 'age' AND value > 18)
```

But if you want to query on two meta/value pairs, you have to join the table unto itself, like so:

```
SELECT a.userID
FROM User AS a
JOIN User AS b ON a.userID = b.userID
WHERE (a.meta = 'age' AND a.value > 18)
  AND (b.meta = 'country' AND b.value = 'Brazil')
```

This way, it "virtually  creates" a table where you would have two meta values and two age values in each line.  You can use `WHERE` conditions to verify conditions on two pairs of meta and value.

The above query results in userID = 1 and = 3 (from the sample data you put in the question).

Comment: No problem.  Which ever answer you will be using, you should click the checkmark besides the answer, so the author will get the reputation points for it.  For the other answer, you can up vote it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
select userID
from Users
group by userID
having max(case when meta = 'age' and cast(value as int) = 18 then 1 end) = 1
   and max(case when meta = 'country' and value = 'Brazil' then 1 end) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Is this what I was looking for! I think the other guy answer is correct too, but I want to do this for more then two columns, and I will need to make more then one join, so, for me, your answer works! Thanks :D

Comment: @Doug This approach is likely to be faster. It's also more easily extended beyond two conditions.

Comment: @shawnt00: I agree, I did not know about that way of doing it, now I know!